# How to save text in TextField via Button click to a variable?

Tags: ios, button, swift, uitextfield

How to simply save written text via click of a "save" button into a variable "a" in Swift?

I tried this

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField! //or UITextView


    //lifecycle methods and so on ...    

    @IBAction func saveTextToVar(sender: UIButton) {
        var text: NSString ?= textField.text
    }
}
```

but while testing my app I always get an error.
http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/584458-1421163318.png

Comment: Please update your question with some information (research or code). Attempt something. Provide details about what issues you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define IBOutlet then connect it with your xib or storyboard.
After you need to define action and connect "Touch up inside" button action with your defined action.

Here the code

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField! //or UITextView


    //lifecycle methods and so on ...    

    @IBAction func saveTextToVar(sender: UIButton) {
        var text: NSString ?= textField.text
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW Swift is a type inference language. You should always use String instead of NSString but just omitting the type is fine.

Comment: Compile time error : Unary operator cannot be separated from its operand on the last line of accepted answer. Try this -> var text = textField.text; println("text value = " + text); Do correct me if i am wrong.